# Can we connect dev org with Environment Hub?

Tags: community, environment-hub

I have create a managed package in developer org where environment hub is enabled.but I have also a business org where Environment hub is also enabled. I want to connect my managed package org with business org. Can we connect these org or Not?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dev org to the Environment Hub.

User Permissions Needed
To connect an organization to the Environment Hub:   “Connect Organization to Environment Hub”

1. Log in to the Environment Hub, and then select Connect Org.
2. Enter the admin username for the org that you want to connect and, optionally, a short description. A description makes it easier to find the org later, especially if your hub has many members.
3. By default, single sign-on (SSO) is enabled for the org you connected.To disable SSO, deselect Auto-enable SSO for this org.
4. Select Connect Org again.
5. In the pop-up window, enter the org’s admin username and password. If you don’t see the pop-up, temporarily disable your browser’s ad blocking software and try again.
6. Select Log In, and then select Allow.

[More Info](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_manage_connect_org.htm)

Comment: Thanks MeighanRocksSF,  i know given step.but my question is different.please read Question one more time.

Comment: So it's not connecting the dev org, it's connecting the business org.  What do you mean by business org?