# Problem connecting Dev Org from Environment Hub of Business Org

Tags: developer-org, environment-hub

I have a managed app in a Dev Org. Now I want to connect it to my main Org. I followed the instructions described in the posting "[Can we connect dev org with Environment Hub?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130990/can-we-connect-dev-org-with-environment-hub?newreg=f2628cdb5f6b40f28db5e030289d7c59)".  I went to the Environment Hub and selected Connect Org, then I enter the system administrator username on the Dev Org. The window that popups up shows the following message. The message refers to a redirect_uri which is mismatched, however, I don't know what I am supposed to set or where to set it.

**error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration**

Comment: The callback URL in the connected app should be the same as you have in your redirect_uri.  Try changing the 'Callback URL' to something like https://swekotest-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/environmenthub/callback.apexp.
 `click-path in the Environment Hub: Setup | Apps | App Manager | choose  'Environment Hub' Connected Apps`

Comment: Okay, I found where to set the callback URL and was able to get it working.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'll post this info as an answer so others can find it helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

The callback URL in the connected app should be the same as you have in your redirect_uri.

You need to set the 'Callback URL' to something like to https://swekotest-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/environmenthub/callback.apexp

Click-path in the Environment Hub(LEX): `Setup | Apps | App Manager | choose 'Environment Hub' in Connected Apps to set callback URL`